# Facebook graph api integration permissions needed for pages_read_engagement while using a test app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am not sure what I have done wrong, I have made a test app from a live app that has a review going for permission to get access to pages_read_engagement
I then created a test app since the current one is live and From what I understood it would inherit our current permissions and pages_read_engagement from the review process.

I also created a test user in the test app that have permission to **pages_read_engagement**

I get the following error when I try to show posts from the current test user in the test app:

> message: "(#10) Object does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permission or reviewable feature, or does not support this operation. This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature

I get the same if I log in with my own account who is administrator for the apps

If I put my current app into developer mode I can get access, but I cannot as it is used for instagram so customers would not have access to their instagram data anymore.

So my question is, how do I get the test user in the test app who got access to pages_read_engagement to actually work so I and facebook can test it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Test users (that is a different thing, than a real user added in the “tester” role) can not interact with real pages. _“I get the same if I log in with my own account who is administrator for the apps”_ - and did you actually grant the permission in that case?

Comment: I don't have the permission maybe? I put started the review process yesterday so I don't have the permissions in the live app as of now, so all I can do is login but not show the actual posts because of this, but I see i miss understood how test apps and test users worked I think, but not sure how to process from here, to test it.

Comment: With test users, you can assign what permissions they are supposed to have granted to your app, in the dashboard. But for any real user account that has a role in the app, you need to _ask_ them for the permission - the same way that is _always_ done, by asking them to grant it during the login to your app. As long as your app is in dev mode, or you are using a dedicated test app version of your app, all users with a role in your app can be asked for any permission, reviewed or not.

Comment: That is what I thought, that is why I am confused that it is giving me this error I posted

Comment: What is actual request you are making? And check if the access token you are using actually contains the permission (debug it, or make a call for /me/permissions.)

Comment: The test user got the access when I test with me/permissions: Object { permission: "pages_read_engagement", status: "granted" } so I am really not sure why it say in the call to:

`document.sp_FB.api(
   '/'+page_url,
   { "fields": "posts{message,full_picture,created_time,is_published},id,name,picture", "access_token": fb_tokens.long, "appsecret_proof": fb_tokens.secret},
   function(fb_respond){
    callback(fb_respond);
   }
  );`

Comment: Test users can not interact with pages created by real users. You would need to login to Facebook as the test user, and have them create a page first.

Comment: OH! Thank you so much, that was the part I missed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as @CBroe wrote, if you use a test user and have set the correct permissions in the test app, then you need to create a page for this to work, you cannot test it with any other pages.